# QT QML Text ElideRight/Wrap combination behavior

Tags: qt, qml

Trying to format a wrapping text box in qt qml, I have the the following:

```
   Text {
        width: 100
        height: 100
        text: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, his at tantas oportereintellegebat"
        wrapMode: Text.Wrap
        elide: Text.ElideRight
        maximumLineCount: 3
    }
```

Resulting in :

```
Lorem ipsum
dolor sit amet, his
at tanta...
```

The eliding is very aggressive here. Ideally, I get as much of the last word into the text box as possible:

```
Lorem ipsum
dolor sit amet, his
at tantas oporte...
```

Which I can sort of get when I change the `wrapMode` to `WrapAnywhere`.

```
Lorem ipsum dolo
r sit amet, his at ta
ntas oportereint...
```

Which is a little too aggressive in cutting words in half. How do I get to a point where I'm not cutting words in half, but also filling out the far end of my text box?

Answer (score 1):

> `Text.WordWrap` - wrapping is done on word boundaries only. If a word is
> too long, contentWidth will exceed a set width.
> https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-text.html#wrapMode-prop